# Is it possible to create a variable but hide it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a script in which the user is able to change the color of the background of a textbox and add a border, I have the background working and the border script working but i cannot seem to figure out how to make adding a border optional, Here's the script:

```js
function newColor(){
 var colorChange = prompt('What color would you like the background?');
    var borderConfirm = confirm('Would you like a border?');
 var borderSize = prompt('Would you like your border to be thin, medium, or thick?');
 var borderColor = prompt('What color would you like your border?');
 if(borderConfirm == true){
   borderSize;
   borderColor;
}  
  else{
    alert('No border will be added');
    }
  document.getElementById('backgroundcolorchange').style.backgroundColor = colorChange;
 document.getElementById('backgroundcolorchange').style.borderWidth = borderSize;
 document.getElementById('backgroundcolorchange').style.borderColor = borderColor; 

 console.log(borderSize);
 console.log(borderColor);
}
```

```css
#backgroundcolorchange{
 background-color:#900;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 position:absolute;
 border:.001px #900 solid; 
}
```

```html
<div id="backgroundcolorchange" onClick="newColor()">
<p id="test" style="margin:0;"> Your Text Will Go Here! </p>
</div>
```

It doesn't give the option until later, I don't know if its something wrong with my variables or my statement. Please help.

Comment: What exact problem are you facing?

Comment: When i run the code it asks if you want to add a border then when you click cancel it still asks for a border size and color

Comment: You're calling prompt outside of your condition, so it is always called. Move the prompt invitation to within the if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function newColor(){
        var colorChange = prompt('What color would you like the background?');
        var borderConfirm = confirm('Would you like a border?');
     if(borderConfirm == true){
      var borderSize = prompt('Would you like your border to be thin, medium, or thick?');
var borderColor = prompt('What color would you like your border?');
    }
```

Comment: The borderSize and borderColor should only be set if borderConfirm is true.

Comment: Then it doesnt ask for the border size and only asks for the color

Comment: And doesnt make a border

Comment: Ohh I see I missed something the first time i read over it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function newColor(){
 var colorChange = prompt('What color would you like the background?');
    var borderConfirm = confirm('Would you like a border?');
 if(borderConfirm == true){
var borderSize = prompt('Would you like your border to be thin, medium, or thick?');
 var borderColor = prompt('What color would you like your border?');
 
  document.getElementById('backgroundcolorchange').style.borderWidth = borderSize;
 document.getElementById('backgroundcolorchange').style.borderColor = borderColor;
}  
  else{
    alert('No border will be added');
    }
  document.getElementById('backgroundcolorchange').style.backgroundColor = colorChange;
  

 console.log(borderSize);
 console.log(borderColor);
}
```

```css
#backgroundcolorchange{
 background-color:#900;
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 position:absolute;
 border:.001px #900 solid; 
}
```

```html
<div id="backgroundcolorchange" onClick="newColor()">
<p id="test" style="margin:0;"> Your Text Will Go Here! </p>
</div>
```